# Setting $cookie_domain variable for specific folder structure

Tags: cookies, configuration, subsites

During configuration of Ckeditor I have to setup the cookie domain variable. I have added my site in subfolder like www.example.com/mynewsitefolder, where www.example.com is my current and running site.
First I tried something like `$cookie_domain = '.example.com/mynewsitefolder';` but that doesn't allow me to log in.

How can I set it, so it works on a sub-folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot set cookie domain to such a value. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

As a workaround, you can use this in settings.php (around where `$cookie_domain` is set:

```
$cookie_domain = ".example.com";
// Set cookie_path ourselves as Drupal doesn't.
ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/mynewsitefolder/');
```

`$cookie_domain` is eventually used to set `session.cookie_domain` but there is nothing in Drupal code base to set `session.cookie_path` and so we directly set that in settings.php itself.